# How to clear/remove/edit echo in PHP

Tags: php, html

For my website I echo out $players. The problem is that this instead of replacing the echo it creates a new one. How can i clear the old echo or delete the old one or edit it so it only has one echo shown.

**If you don't understand what I mean (I don't blame you), this is the website:**

[Page Of Site](http://mathrace.000webhostapp.com/createcode.php?hello=true)

**Code:**

```php
while(isset($_GET['hello'])) {
         sleep(1);
        $result = $conn->query("SELECT id FROM gamecode WHERE gamecode = '$gameCode'"); 
      $players = $result->num_rows; 
    echo "<h4>$players Players</h4>";
    flush();
}
```

**Thank you so much for any help you give me.**

Comment: How often does the database update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need both server side (PHP) and client side (javascript) to achieve this goal.

Server side: only echo once, discard the while loop;

Client side: call server side (ajax or refresh the whole page) every n second to get the latest data.

Example:

(1) Create a new php file "nowStat.php", and move your db query into this file, like:

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT id FROM gamecode WHERE gamecode = '$gameCode'"); 
$players = $result->num_rows; 
echo "$players Players";
```

(2) In your createcode.php file, define an empty `<h4>` or `<div>` with an id:

```
<h4 id="playerStatus"></h4>
```

Then in the same file use jQuery/Ajax to retrieve the status every 5 sec:

```
setInterval(function() { $("#playerStatus").load("nowStat.php"); }, 5000);
```

Here is a very simple tutorial about jQuery/Ajax: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: See my updated answer, but it's more like pseudo-code. You will need to write your own code to make it more desirable.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

remove the `echo` statement within your `while` loop because the code will always be triggered so long as your `hello` is true

Comment: It needs to always be running, i cant just remove it. It needs to constantly be checking if the value needs to chnage

Comment: if it need to keep running and you want to change to value to new one while removing the old one, the only way to this IMO, is by using AJAX call to the php script.